# Find First and Last Row Index after autofilter VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Ive a sheet with more than 10000 rows of data. I need to filter it based on a date range in a column (Column F). But after filtering how can I find the Row index of first and last row in that Filtered data. Means First row index could be 120 and last row index could be 3200 something like that. What I tried is as follows to find the last row which is not working at all.

```
Public Sub clearExistingInvoice()
    Dim minDate As Date, maxDate As Date
    minDate = "10 FEB 2018" ' invoiceMinDate
    maxDate = "20 FEB 2018" 'invoiceMaxDate
    Dim minPosition As Integer
    Sheets("FullInvoice").UsedRange.AutoFilter
    Sheets("FullInvoice").UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=">=" & minDate, Criteria2:="<=" & maxDate
    Dim xRange As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = Sheets("FullInvoice").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows
    lRow = Sheets("FullInvoice").UsedRange.Cells(1, 1).Row

    Set xRange = Sheets("FullInvoice").Range("F65000")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to exploit the Areas property of Range object that allows you to handle each adjacent cells subrange of a given Range 
I’n not by PC but the following should get you in the way:

```
With Sheets("FullInvoice").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    firstRow = .Areas(1).Rows(1).Row ‘get first subrange first row index
    With .Areas(.Areas.Count) ‘reference last subrange
        lastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row ‘get referenced subrange last row index
    End With 
End With
```

Comment: @SandeepThomas, any feedback?

Comment: @SandeepThomas, I see you keep asking questions, and that's good. but would you mind closing all of them? thank you

Comment: @SandeepThomas, ...any chance to close this topic?